# Why is my open and save feature using javafx not working?

Tags: javafx, save, filestream

I am creating a 'save' to a specific file and an 'open' from the specific file. The save feature was working but since I have implemented the 'open' feature it has now stopped working. When the open feature is run I am printing it's contents to the console but at the moment the below error is shown in the console and only the first item of the array list is shown in the console. The 'open' and 'save' features are right at the bottom of my code but just before my two classes 'Record' and 'Getrecord' which are used for the 'save' and 'open' functions. I am very confused and not sure how to proceed as I don't know whats wrong.

How the code appears:

```
miOpen.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                FileInputStream fis=null;
                try{
                    fis = new FileInputStream("testsave.txt");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("TEST OPEN B4");





                    String openstring = new String();


                    BufferedReader bwo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                    try {
                        while( (openstring=bwo.readLine()) != null) {

                            String [] g = openstring.split(",");
                            System.out.println("TEST OPEN");
                            System.out.println(openstring);

                            getrecordsarray.add(new Getrecord(g[0], Double.parseDouble(g[1]), Double.parseDouble(g[2]), Double.parseDouble(g[3]), Double.parseDouble(g[4]), Double.parseDouble(g[5]), Double.parseDouble(g[6]), Double.parseDouble(g[7])));
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        fis.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }});

miSave.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    fileChooser.setTitle("testsave1.txt");
                     try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testsave1.txt", true))) {
                            for(Record r : records)
                            bw.write(r.name + "," + r.age + "," + r.gender + "," + r.ethnicity + "," + r.answerA + "," + r.answerB + "," + r.answerC + "," + count);
                            bw.newLine();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }


                     System.out.println("SAVED");

                     if (autoreturn==1){

                         System.out.println("saved fade");
                         FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), savemsg1);
                         ft.setFromValue(0);
                         ft.setToValue(1);



                         ft.play();

                         FadeTransition ft2 = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), savemsgl1);
                         ft2.setFromValue(0);
                         ft2.setToValue(1);



                         ft2.play();



                     }  

                }});


        }

void saveFile(File save)
{
FileOutputStream fos=null;
try{
    fos = new FileOutputStream(save);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}





try{
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();
}
}



                }
```

This error is thrown in the console when the 'open' button is run:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at SurveyApp$10.handle(SurveyApp.java:1181)
    at SurveyApp$10.handle(SurveyApp.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the text you read in from the file and try to split via ',' doesn't consist of the structure you expect with the hard-coded array indices:

```
getrecordsarray.add(new Getrecord(g[0], Double.parseDouble(g[1]), Double.parseDouble(g[2]), Double.parseDouble(g[3]), Double.parseDouble(g[4]), Double.parseDouble(g[5]), Double.parseDouble(g[6]), Double.parseDouble(g[7])));
```

Comment: This is a typical structure from my file: dave,34,2,3,3,3,3,1- does this not match that structure?

Comment: You provide no information what your files look like. There could be a blank line and what not. Just write the g[] to the console (Arrays.toString()) and check it or use a debugger.

Comment: Since you're already printing each line to the console, you can figure out which line in the file you're reading causes the error: it's the first line after the last line that was output before the stack trace.

Comment: My guess is that you also need to check for openstring.trim().isEmpty() which would probably apply to the last line in your textfile.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to this line that is causing the error:             getrecordsarray.add(new Getrecord(g[0], Double.parseDouble(g[1]), Double.parseDouble(g[2]), Double.parseDouble(g[3]), Double.parseDouble(g[4]), Double.parseDouble(g[5]), Double.parseDouble(g[6]), Double.parseDouble(g[7])));

Comment: Yes, line 1181. That's what the stacktrace says. And my answer.